# calling base constructor from derived constructor in python

Tags: python

what should be done in order to execute it

```
class parent():
    age=None
    name=None
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
    def printout(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.age) 

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self,name,age,gender):
        super(parent,self).__init__(self.name,self.age)
        print gender

c=child("xyz",22,"male")
c.printout()
```

I am a newbie in the world of python, unable to figure out what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super()` only works for *new-style* classes; add `object` to the base classes for `parent`:

```
class parent(object):
```

You may want to adjust your `super()` call as well. You need to give the *current* class, not the `parent` class to start searching from, and `self.name` and `self.age` are still set to `None` by the time your `__init__` is called, but you seem to want to pass on the `name` and `age` arguments:

```
def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
    super(child, self).__init__(name, age)
    print gender
```

With these changes, the code works:

```
>>> c = child("xyz", 22, "male")
male
>>> c.printout()
xyz
22
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inherit from `object` to make `super()` work, also `self.name` and `self.age` are always `None` when you pass them to the `super()` call.

```
class parent(object):
```

And:

```
super(child, self).__init__(name, age)
```

Comment: Yes, they have been set; *on the class*. That's probably not what the OP wants, however. ;-)

Comment: Ah, up there on the class itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`super()` works for new style classes only (In Python3, everything is new style). SO you need

```
class parent(object):
```

Also in call to super, the first argument is the name of the *child* class not the parent class. The call in child class should be

```
super(child, self).__init__(name, age)
```